# load ssl certificate in haproxy with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, haproxy

Hi I have `haproxy` in `docker-compose` as below -

```
 haproxy:
  image: haproxy:2.3
  depends_on:
   - my-service
  volumes:
   - ./config/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
   - ./ssl:/usr/local/etc/ssl:ro
  ports:
   - 80:80
```

haproxy.config

```
 frontend https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/ssl/cert1.pem
```

but when I am doing `docker-compose up -d` always I am getting

```
 unable to stat SSL certificate from file '/etc/ssl/cert1.pem' : No such file or directory.
```

I do not understand how to pass certificate to haproxy or what am I missing here. Can someone help on this.

I have `ssl` directory in my local from which I am moving certificate to `/usr/local/etc/ssl` in container

Comment: `haproxy.config` is a typo? Your `docker-compose` uses `haproxy.cfg`.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the SSL folder to /usr/local/etc/ssl, and the error says it is  looking for the file in /etc/ssl.

Do you need to remap the folder to /etc/ssl?
eg.

```
- ./ssl:/etc/ssl:ro
```